# How to share files with Samba in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: samba

How can I connect to share my file in other wireless network systems? I am now using Ubuntu 14.04.

```
bnogroups@bnogroups:~$ sudo apt-get install samba
sudo mkdir -p /srv/samba/share
bnogroups@bnogroups:~$ sudo chown nobody:nogroup /srv/samba/share/
bnogroups@bnogroups:~$ sudo restart smbd
smbd start/running, process 4441
bnogroups@bnogroups:~$ sudo restart nmbd
nmbd start/running, process 4452
```

Comment: how do you want to share files from Ubuntu 14.04 to windows?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with other wireless network ?? other network like WAN ?? VPN??

edit de samba.conf in the follow sections

`sudo nano -w /etc/samba/smb.conf`

[homes]

comment = Home Directories

browseable = yes

read only = no

run this three commands in the terminal and follow the steps

```
sudo  smbpasswd -a yourName

sudo smbpasswd -e username
sudo /etc/init.d/samba reload
```